# Django custom form - is_valid does not call clean method when __init__ method available

Tags: python, django

I have the following custom form code in Django:

```
class JoinMeetingForm(forms.Form):
    meeting_id = forms.UUIDField(help_text="Enter the UUID")

    def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
        self.user=user
        super(JoinMeetingForm,self).__init__(*args)

    def clean_meeting_id(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['meeting_id']

        meeting = Meeting.objects.filter(pk=data)

        querySuccess = False

        if len(meeting) == 1:
            if(meeting[0].joined_user==None):
                querySuccess = True # ToDo

        return data
```

First, I call JoinMeetingForm(request.user), which calls the init method.
Then, I call form.is_valid(), however, this does not call the clean_meeting_id() method - why is this the case? Strangely, if I comment out the init method, the is_valid() method calls the clean_meeting_id() method.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the **`meeting_id`** data into the form and hence the form not calling the *"field validator method"* (because there is no data for `meeting_id`)

So, it should be something like,

```
form = JoinMeetingForm(
    request.user,
    {"meeting_id": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000"}
)
is_valid = form.is_valid()
```